# How can i count cells in excel? Need to count how many say win, and how many say loss

Tags: excel, variables, count

How can i count cells in excel? Need to count how many say win, and how many say loss. For example column C contains either the word WIN or LOSS. i want to have a cell that counts that and displays a record (ex. 23-11) Ive been trying IF functions but i cant get it to go through and count them all. im thinking i need a variable to keep track of the wins and losses. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will need this formula

```
=CONCATENATE(COUNTIF(A1:A9,"WIN")," - ",COUNTIF(A1:A9,"LOSS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from a formula, something like `=COUNTIF(C:C,"WIN")+COUNTIF(C:C,"LOSS")` should work. If it's not, then you might have trailing whitespace or something that keeps the values from being exactly "WIN" or "LOSS" but instead "WIN " or the like.